# How do I put the image at top followed by the heading for my thesis?

Tags: graphics

[image]

The image shows what I want for my thesis. I created a separate chapter named as **Certificate of Approval** in my **main.tex** file. The structure of the code is given below.

```
\chapter*{Certificate of Approval}
\inputgraphicx[width = 0.5\textwidth]{image.png}
Some text goes here
```

How do I create the recreate the image in my thesis?

Answer (score 1):

```
\chapter*{Certificate of Approval}
\begin{figure}[t!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{newlogo.png}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
Some text  here
```

This did the trick for me.

Comment: Since \chapter already flushes the float queue, the only possibly use of [!] would be if the figure takes up more than 70% of the page (if then).